# Why Chromecast not working over ethernet cable?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, chromecast

I see that Chromecast only show up on my smartphone when I connect the Chromecast with wifi, but when I switch to Ethernet cable, the cast icon disappear.

Many people have the same question:

- [Chromecast Ultra not working over Ethernet ever since switching to
  AT&T](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/ac3era/chromecast_ultra_not_working_over_ethernet_ever/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)
- [Why does my Chromecast Ultra disappear when I connect it
  with an ethernet cable?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/7ngwdi/why_does_my_chromecast_ultra_disappear_when_i/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

(I make this question because I want to give a better answer)

Comment: It comes down to how your router is likely setup. Sometimes it doesn't allow wired & wireless to speak to each other OR wireless & wireless for security. If you can detail your router model that would be helpful. Also the IP of the Chromecast & the IP of your wireless casting gadget (ie: smartphone/tablet) so we can at least confirm they are on the same subnet

Comment: @gregg - I see, but currently I'm just too chicken to mess up the router settings (because other family member will kill me if there is no internet in 1 minute). Currently, the solution "Ethernet for casting device" is my best choice.

Comment: I'd mark your reply as the answer so no one else wastes time replying then since you are happy with the solution you found

Comment: @gregg - actually, I try to find the solution that I can cast the video from smartphone via wifi without having to unplug Ethernet cable, I hope that Google implemented a way to soft-disable Ethernet like Windows did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>If your Chromecast uses Ethernet cable, then the casting device (PC, Tablet) must also use Ethernet cable.</s>

For example, this will work (tested and work on a Windows PC, successfully cast Youtube, Dailymotion,...):

- step 1: Connect your ChromeCast with the Ethernet cable.
- step 2: Connect your PC with the Ethernet cable.
- step 3: On your PC, open **Google Chrome** (not Firefox, only Google Chrome, because Google Chrome has cast feature), open a video on Youtube, then you should see the cast button that can cast to your ChromeCast.

There is [a useful article](https://www.howtogeek.com/296622/how-to-use-ethernet-with-your-chromecast-for-fast-and-reliable-streaming/) about this.

New discovery, I was wrong. Chromecast does work over Ethernet cable. I can cast from my smartphone to my Chromecast when my Chromecast uses Ethernet and my smartphone uses Wifi. (Note: my Chromecast is actually a TV Box that runs Android TV 10)

The reason it didn't work before is that my cousin incorrectly setup the wifi's Router IP address: My house has 2 routers, the main router doesn't enable wifi, the secondary router enables wifi, but the IP address of the 2 routers doesn't match (main router (ethernet): 192.168.1.1, secondary router (wifi): 192.168.3.1 --> doesn't match so here is the problem).

I have to re-setup my routers to make the IP address matches. To do it, I follow this video instruction "How To Connect Two Routers On One Home Network Using A Lan Cable": https://youtu.be/J5QJb3O19zI

I recommend you to watch the video instruction to setup the routers, here is the general idea:

Main router: IP Address: `192.168.1.1`; Enable `Use Router as DHCP Server: [192.168.1.20, 192.168.1.254]`.

Secondary router: IP Address: `192.168.1.2`; Disable `Use Router as DHCP Server`.

Connect the Secondary router to the Main router: `Main router's LAN port <----LAN cable---> Secondary router's LAN port`. Note: plug the LAN cable into LAN port, not WAN port.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by putting the same name of the WIFI connection, to the Network Profile Name on my LAN.

Here it is explained:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/28375-change-network-profile-name-windows-10-a.html#option2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).